# apk does not compile on linux server when called from browser but works when called from terminal

Tags: php, android, linux, shell, apk

I'm trying to compile and package apk on a linux headless server. here's what I've done so far:

- I installed android sdk, all ok
- I installed ant, all ok

I am able to build an android project from terminal all ok
and even I am able to call a bash file from the terminal, and it does build the apk for me fine. here's the bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/zipalign
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jdk
export PATH=$PATH:/root/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:/root/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/root/android-sdk-linux/platforms
export PATH=$PATH:/root/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/root/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin/ant
export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/ant/bin
ant release
echo "DONE"
```

and then I am able to call the php file from terminal which runs the bash file and again it works fine and the apk is built. here's the php code:

```
<?php 
   $output = shell_exec("./javaApk.sh");
   echo $output;
?>
```

the weird thing is that when I call this php from browser, it does not build the apk! It just returns the following in the browser but no apk!

```
Buildfile: /var/www/1/air.com.domain.FreshApp/java_apk/build.xml DONE
```

and when I echo $PATH in my bash file (running the php from browser) I can see the following result which seems all fine

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/var/www/uploads/zipalign:/usr/local/ant/bin:/usr/local/ant/lib:/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jdk:/root/android-sdk-linux:/root/android-sdk-linux/tools:/root/android-sdk-linux/platforms:/root/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/root/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin/ant:/var/www/uploads/ant/bin
```

any idea?

Comment: MIght it be a rights problem? I assume your php runs under a different user then you use when you log in. Can your php user (www-data?) write everywhere it should? or read?

Comment: For testing you can run your script from terminal (php cli). As @Nanne said - try it from the same user that builds apk with success.

Comment: @Nanne: yes, my php user is "www-data" and permissions are 0777

Comment: @hsz: yes, I can run the php from terminal and it works just fine! "php javaApk.php"

Comment: I doubt that all permissions are 0777. Look at the path, the libraries, everything. The fact that it works through php from the terminal kinda suggests that it is just that: a problem with permissions, or maybe paths (calling it though apache also puts you in a different dir probably?

Comment: @Nanne the bash file/the ant file permission is also 0777, what other files do you think I should set permission for?! (I edited my post to show you the $PATH when calling from browser, php)